# Which the better way to make carousel view in swift with open - animation (expanding)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, carousel

I need to make carousel view in swift with "opening-animation".

First of all, I have created scroll view, after that have created subViews with my customView, maked my scrollView paged-enabled, and it's okay, **but I need to make it expanding by swipe gesture.** I added animation, but this view can't be higher than scrollView height, so I need to make this width and height (after gesture) like viewController's view height and width. **And, it's the problem.**

What's better way to do this?

Example screen:
[BeforeGesture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogwJz.png)

Second example screen: [after up-swipe gesture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUtx4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to handle it using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` gesture which will give you the better control on all the different states of pan (drag began, drag ended). In your drag ended state you can handle the logic of increasing the height of scrollview and after that add the animation to show the expanded view with animation effect.

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: So, do you think, that I need to increase the height of UIScrollView too?

Comment: Yes, you need to increase the contentsize of scrollview.

Comment: I will try tomorrow, and give you the feedback, thank you